# Tomcat and Eclipse Real Website

Tags: java, eclipse, html, tomcat7

I have created a website running on eclipse and tomcat. What is the way to make this website running online for real?? I have developed it, adding filters and sessions and using a database. I want to allow people to use this website. What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to publically expose your computer and the port you set up.

If your application runs locally, it must be able to be hit by the outside world.

Make sure the tomcat config is setup correctly and ensure port forwarding on your router or modem is setup. Your public IP (available if you google whats my ip) and the port is all your users would need.